Task Scheduler Running Multiple Instances
I am encountering an issue with Task Scheduler on a Windows Server. I have a startup task that runs a program/script via Git Bash, which points to a .sh file that executes a Python script every minute.
Problem: The task is running the same event multiple times. Despite my efforts to stop it, including setting the task to stop if it runs longer than 1 minute and configuring it to not start new instances if the task is already running, the issue persists. The last step I took was deleting the task, but I am still receiving logs from the Python script, indicating that it is still running.I even changed my entire script to a hello world and the old version still runs
Steps Taken:

Configured Task Scheduler to run a program/script using Git Bash.
Set the task to run a .sh file that executes a Python script every minute.
Attempted to stop the task with settings:
Stop the task if it runs longer than 1 minute.
Do not start a new instance if the task is already running.
Deleted the task from Task Scheduler.
Issue: Despite deleting the task, I am still receiving logs from the Python script, indicating that the old versions of the script are still running. Could this be related to multiple user accounts or residual processes that are not being terminated properly?

Questions:
Is it possible that Task Scheduler is running the task for multiple user accounts?
Could there be any residual processes that are not being terminated properly?
Are there any other troubleshooting steps I can take to ensure that old versions of the script are not running?

Any resolution to this? Seeing the same thing.
